# A cross-platform manner to create a process

Tags: c, windows, winapi, vlc, createprocess

I need to launch VLC from a C program, and I would like to find a cross-platform manner to do so.

Of course, I know that I am going to use two different functions (fork and CreateProcess) for Linux and Windows. What I don't know is how I can launch VLC from Windows. Reading the official documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I saw that I have to use the absolute path of the executable file. How can I retrieve the absolute path of the directory where VLC has been installed?

---

I imagine that my code will look like this:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
// use CreateProcess
#else
// use fork
#endif
```

What I don't know yet is how I can dynamically retrieve the path of VLC.

---

UPDATE

Maybe I found an alternative way to obtain the same result. It's a little bit more tricky but it should work.
libvlc provides a function to play a media file directly from C code. Here is a link to the [official documentation](http://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__list.html)

Comment: AFAIK the installation path is a system-dependent notion, so you have to have system-dependent code in your program.

Comment: Maybe you can find the path somewhere in the registry?

Comment: @Luchian: apparently, current versions of VLC no longer set up register entries - in the past, one could query HKLM\Software\VideoLAN\VLC\; in fact, on my machine it even did not register the uninstaller oO

Comment: do you actually need to launch VLC? it's probably easier to use the program associated with a given file type...

Comment: you seem to have found a more appropriate way to overcome your specific problem. it might however be worth re-wording your title to something along the lines of `how I can programmatically retrieve the path of an exe...` as i think this is a generally useful winOS question esp. for apps that appear to avoid the registry,, & i am given to think also, that SO attempts to discourage *niche* questions ~jmo, & best of luck =)

Comment: If you want something has similar syntax on both systems try _spawn on Windows and posix_spawn on Linux.